# How to use "\newline" in python

Tags: python, escaping, read-eval-print-loop

I wanted to know the usage of `\newline` and how to use it.
From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals), it says:-

> `\newline` :- Backslash and newline ignored

I tried using it as follows in REPL:

```
>>> a="first\newline"
>>> print(a)
first
ewline
```

I instead intreprets as `\n`(*LineFeed*).